# Encypted LV "not a valid LUKS device" after Debian Setup

Tags: debian, debian-installer, cryptsetup

I've just set up a Debian system to try out a couple of projects and improve my understanding of Linux but I'm running into problems with cryptsetup straight after installation. I used the graphical installer for Debian 9 and used its baked-in encryption tool to encrypt /home and the swap space which I have set up as logical volumes.

I'm trying to change the encryption passphrase for each drive, after I stupidly left caps-lock on after setting up the partitions.

I'd hoped I'd be able to do this simply using cryptsetup luksChangeKey. However, whenever I attempt to access either the devices/containers with cryptsetup (running as root) I seem to get the error:

```
<device> is not a valid LUKS device.
```

Please find outputs from lsblk, ls /dev/mapper and cryptsetup below, which I hope give a good indication of how I'm set up and the problems I'm experiencing:

```
lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                            8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1                         8:1    0   953M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                         8:2    0   477M  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                         8:3    0 110.4G  0 part  
  ├─SSD1_LVM-LV_ROOT         254:0    0   7.5G  0 lvm   /
  ├─SSD1_LVM-LV_VAR          254:1    0  14.9G  0 lvm   /var
  ├─SSD1_LVM-LV_TMP          254:2    0   7.5G  0 lvm   /tmp
  ├─SSD1_LVM-LV_USR          254:3    0  29.8G  0 lvm   /usr
  ├─SSD1_LVM-LV_HOME         254:4    0   7.5G  0 lvm   
  │ └─SSD1_LVM-LV_HOME_crypt 254:8    0   7.5G  0 crypt /home
  ├─SSD1_LVM-LV_OPT          254:5    0  14.9G  0 lvm   /opt
  └─SSD1_LVM-LV_SWAP         254:6    0  15.9G  0 lvm   
    └─SSD1_LVM-LV_SWAP_crypt 254:7    0  15.9G  0 crypt 
ls -l /dev/mapper
total 0
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 Sep 27 09:35 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Sep 27 09:36 SSD1_LVM-LV_HOME -> ../dm-4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Sep 27 09:36 SSD1_LVM-LV_HOME_crypt -> ../dm-8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Sep 27 09:35 SSD1_LVM-LV_OPT -> ../dm-5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Sep 27 09:35 SSD1_LVM-LV_ROOT -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Sep 27 09:35 SSD1_LVM-LV_SWAP -> ../dm-6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Sep 27 15:50 SSD1_LVM-LV_SWAP_crypt -> ../dm-7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Sep 27 09:35 SSD1_LVM-LV_TMP -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Sep 27 09:35 SSD1_LVM-LV_USR -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Sep 27 09:35 SSD1_LVM-LV_VAR -> ../dm-1
cryptsetup status /dev/dm-7
/dev/dm-7 is active.
  type:    LUKS1
  cipher:  aes-xts-plain64
  keysize: 512 bits
  device:  /dev/mapper/SSD1_LVM-LV_SWAP
  offset:  4096 sectors
  size:    33198080 sectors
  mode:    read/write
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/dm-7
Device /dev/dm-7 is not a valid LUKS device.
```

I disabled disk swap space with swapoff in case that was causing problems, which regrettably hasn't helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run `cryptsetup` on the device that holds the LUKS header (for actions that modify the header, i.e. format, key management, dump, ...).

In your case, this is `/dev/mapper/SSD1_LVM-LV_SWAP`

But you tried to run it on `/dev/mapper/SSD1_LVM-LV_SWAP_crypt` which is the swap LV (encrypted) and presumably holds a swap header (mkswap) instead of a LUKS header (that would be luks inside luks...).

Comment: That's cleared it up! It's quirks like this which I'm struggling to pick out from sifting through the man and --help documentation. Thank you so much.